# I want to show multiple user profile pics on the same page as well as image upload field

Tags: 7

I want to show multiple user profile pictures on the same page, as well as an image upload field where users can easily upload, add, and delete their profile pics. I want to use a single page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `multiple user profile pictures` are those multiple pics from the same user, or different users?

Comment: from the same user

Comment: Did you set the user picture to unlimited value?

Comment: the main profile pic will be one it will show in seprate block in left column and the correspong profile pics of the same user will show in another seperate block in right coloum and profile pic upload field just below these blocks

Comment: but there is no option for selecting multiple profile pics

Comment: will u please let me know how to show profile edit fields on the display page where user can upload pics

Comment: humm... you could create a new image field called Avatar with unlimited value and use that for your user pics. Go to `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`